# Make SQL replicate over separate VLAN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, vlan

I have two SQL Server 2008 machines, SQL1 and SQL2, doing replication between each other. Their main interfaces are on VLAN1 (10.1.1.0/24) and that's where clients reach them.

For performance, I want the replication to go over their secondary NICs, which are on VLAN2 (10.1.2.0/24).

Is there any way to configure this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that both SQL machines are listening on that second VLAN. You can test this by logging on to one via the console or remote desktop and then connecting directly to the IP of the other using SSMS or SQLCMD. If that's the case, set up an alias on both systems using SQL Server Configuration Manager pointing to the IP of the other server on that second VLAN. Set up the replication to use that alias name.